# Vue JS server not compiling after changes to src files

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, npm

I am new to Vue.js and I am having an issue and have been stuck for a long while trying different fixes.

After starting a dev server using npm run serve, I would expect that when I make changes to any .vue or .js files within my directory, the server would refresh and display these changes. However, no matter what I try nothing happens. Nothing is compiling and nothing changes within my terminal. The only way I can refresh the server is by closing it and running a new one. Refreshing my browser page does nothing either. Really stumped on this one so will be eternally grateful if anyone can help as none of the fixes I found on here have worked for me :(

My vue.config.js is as follows:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    client: {
      progress: true
    },
    hot: false,
    watchFiles: {
      paths: ['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.vue', 'src/**/*.json', 'src/views/*.vue']
    },
    liveReload: true,
  }
})
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "product-and-cart",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.54.5",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

And my jsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }
}
```

And babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `vue.config.js` file, you set [hot module replacement](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhot) to false in `devServer` configuration; therefore, your changes won't be applied without refreshing the page. Hot module replacement is enabled by default in Vue CLI, you can remove `hot` from the configuration. Also, you don't have to set `liveReload` and `watch` options for this.

For more details, you can take a look at [Vue CLI configuration](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/) and [Webpack DevServer configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/).

Comment: Thanks for the response Utku. I actually didn't have those settings defined in my vue.config.js previously, and added them in search for a fix. However, if I remove them, when I make a change to a file within the src folder it still doesn't make any changes. Within my terminal it doesn't re-compile and even if I refresh the web page it doesn't change. I cant work out what the issue is, that's causing the server not to compile, but that seems to be the core issue. Do you have any ideas on what else it could be? Thanks again! :D

Comment: Did you restart the dev server after applying changes to configuration? If not, probably, you need to restart it to take effect.

Comment: Yeah since it would not compile or refresh without me restarting the dev server I tried that many times too, still no luck :(